# How to send image from clipboard on Ubuntu to clipboard on Android using KDE Connect?

Tags: 20.04, file-sharing, clipboard, kde-connect

If I copy a text on my Ubuntu 20.04 then it instantly appears on my Samsung tablet's clipboard.

But if I copy an image to the clipboard on Ubuntu (using `ctrl` + `shift` + `printscreen`) then the image does not appear on my Samsung tablet's clipboard.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'd like to know that too

Comment: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=451258